# OTRS PostMasterMailBox.pl not a scalar reference

Tags: perl, email, otrs

I have just upgraded OTRS from 3 to 3.3. Before we retrieved emails from a mailbox, but it's not working now, the credentials has been verified multiple times and for all I can understand it connects just fine. We have not changed anything in the files, so we aren't quite sure what is up.

The error is:
    "Not a SCALAR reference at /usr/share/perl15/Mail/IMAPClient.pm line 419"

[image: Complete error]

This is the snippet of IMapClient.pm:419:

```
# give caller control of args to start_SSL if desired
my @sslargs =
    ( $self->Starttls and ref( $self->Starttls ) eq "ARRAY" )
  ? ( @${ $self->Starttls } )
  : ( Timeout => 30 );

unless ( $ioclass->start_SSL( $sock, @sslargs ) ) {
    $self->LastError( "Unable to start TLS: " . $ioclass->errstr );
    return undef;
}
```

Edit: We had to do  quick downgrade and that fixed the problem entirely, so I wonder if it's a bug in OTRS?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the installed Perl Modules using otrs.CheckModules.pl?

Comment: Yes, all of them. It has turned out to be even more funky now. We set up a completely identical test environment (images of our servers and so on) to test on. On our test environment, this script works absolutely fine. The second we throw it on to the productions server it wont run.